# Understanding Passportjs Custom Callback

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I'm experimenting with Passportjs and the code for a Custom Callback is:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

I'm happy with all of this code except for the second to last line `(req, res, next);` - Could someone explain why these parameters are added on the end. This is probably more of a JS question than a Passport question but any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's a passport question as well. Apparently, `passport.authenticate(…)` does return a function.

Comment: Looks like it's designed to be written as `app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {…}));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "javascript" answer is that it returns a function which is called again with those 2nd set of arguments.

That function is the "accumulator for failures from each strategy in the chain".

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it without the anonymous function, or the custom callback. Just use passport's `passport.use(new LocalStrategy())` function to create the new strategy. [See 'Configure' docs](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/).

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    logIn({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

The only change you need to make is move the `logIn` function to be in this file, and not a method to `req`. Then you can simply call `passport.authenticate` like so:

```
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                                   failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

So instead of using res.redirect in the callback, you just use passport's built in `successRedirect` and `failureRedirect` properties. You can see their docs as well, on the [authentication page](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/).

Comment: It looks like in your example you are missing (req, res, next). How do you call res.redirect() without them?  I really like your response though because I have a common callback I want to use.

Comment: @Chris updated the answer to work better. You should probably not use a callback, but instead use the actual authentication function to do all the work. Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the adjustment, but that was actually what I was trying to get away from. :)  I'm using this for an API auth, and I don't want to redirect.  I'm using it to customize my API response with the correct Response Code, and also pass the message with my response.

Comment: @Chris is this for sending different data for authenticated and unauthenticated routes? Theres a passport authentication strategy for that: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-anonymous

Answer (score 1):

*Connect/Express* middleware function has signature:

```
function(req, res, next)
```

`passport.authenticate()` can be used as a middleware, e.g:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), nextMiddleware);
```

This means `authenticate()` returns a middleware function object, which you can evoke with `(req, res, next)` parameters to continue the app's request-response cycle.