# passportjs custom callback code flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am new to passportJS, and want to understand this code:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Can someone explain to me flow of this code? and what `(req, res, next);` do in the end of passport.authenticate function?

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523336/understanding-passportjs-custom-callback) question too, but still don't get it.

Comment: Well, it handles the routing for 'login', and it tries to authenticate at local level, and if it encounters any error it displays the same, if the user is not authenticated redirects him to login, othewise he will get redirected to the `\users` route/page. The `(req, res, next)` are actually the values you are passing to the function arguments.

Comment: "The (req, res, next) are actually the values you are passing to the function arguments."

sorry, what function do you mean?

Comment: So the (req, res, next); is contains login callbacks?
If it's right what the function of (req, res, next) related to the passport.authenticate function?

Answer (score 0):

```
passport.authenticate()(<args>);
```

`passport.authenticate()` returns a function that can have three arguments (`req`,`res`,`next`). The code/arguments that you are asking about are these arguments which are passed to the function that is returned by `passport.authenticate()` Check the [authenticate.js code on GitHub](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/tree/master/lib/middleware/authenticate.js)

However, I am not very clear about what does passport do with string `local`. I would like to know:

1. Is passing `local` string sufficient for Passport to understand what
   authentication mechanism to apply?
2. What does passport do (and how) after encountering use of `local` strategy?

Comment: it appears that while defining the passport strategy e.g. passport.use('strategyname', new StrategyClass()); we declare the name of the strategy. This name is later used in passport.authenticate('strategyName', ..);