# What is the (req, res) after passport authenticate for?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

In passport.js, I notice when people use the authenticate method, they sometimes add (req, res, next?) after calling the method. What does this do exactly?

E.g. A little snippet from here: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/authenticator.js

```
passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false })(req, res);
```

Thank you

Comment: This is clearly spelled out in the documentation.

Comment: That was fast. Could you please point me to where in the documentation that explains this. I have had no luck so far

Comment: Please do not treat Stack Overflow like Google. Go to the docs on one of those sites and look at the documentation link.

Comment: That's what I've been doing for the past hour and no luck, hence why I am here. Why do you assume this is my first solution?
I resorted to reading the source to find out more and still can't figure it out. If you clearly know the answer, why not just share and help others like me who might be stuck on this.

Comment: the key phrase is "route middleware" https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport#authenticate-requests - perhaps you need to brush up on what middleware is :p

Comment: Thank you Jaromanda. I am new and still learning. Thanks for pointing me in a direction

Comment: @BayoO'liliJason' it's explained fairly well here if you scroll down to the 'Custom Callback' section: http://www.passportjs.org/docs

Comment: @JaromandaX where does that link show calling the result of `authenticate()` in the manner described in the OP? That's clearly not the way most middleware works.

Comment: Ah, closure. @Mark_M Thank you so much!!!! Finally makes sense.You should post it up as an answer so i can upvote it.

Comment: Now that I know what I;m looking for, here is another discussion on the same topic for anyone else who is curious - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523336/understanding-passportjs-custom-callback

Comment: yeah, didn't notice that difference @Mark_M

Comment: Had the same question, read the docs and it said that's a closure. Lets the passport authenticate function which is an inner function have access to the outer function async (req, res, next). Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passport is authentication middleware for Node.js i.e. it checks whether an API request being made is from an authenticated source.
So every time an API request is made,the request (req) passes through the authentication strategy used by passport,and if succesfully authenticated,then passport binds the details of the user to the request(req).

So in your case, **if authentication was successfull,then req shall contain more details about the user who is requesting for the API**.You can now be sure that the API request (req) is from an authenticated source.

For a better understanding,you might want to have a look at the following:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-http

https://github.com/passport/express-3.x-http-basic-example/blob/master/server.js

Answer (score 0):

`passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false })` is the first part of the code. It calls the `passport.authenticate()` function. This function call **returns** a **middleware** function specific to the **basic** **authentication** strategy.

`(req, res)` invokes the **middleware function returned** by `passport.authenticate()` with **req** and **res** as arguments to the middleware function.

By combining these two parts together, the authentication middleware is executed within the route handler.